# How can remapping [ to { and { to [ with AutoHotKey

Tags: autohotkey

I want to switch the <kbd>{</kbd> key with <kbd>[</kbd>, so I don't have to use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> anymore to make <kbd>{</kbd> and I do have to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> key to make <kbd>[</kbd>...

same question for switching <kbd>,</kbd> to <kbd><</kbd> and vice versa.

I know only how to make the first part work:

[::{

However, switching <kbd>{</kbd> with <kbd>[</kbd> doesn't work when I try the following:

{::[

How do I insert the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key?

Comment: @Mihai You might want to clarify exactly what you mean by shift to make [ and other...

Comment: @Armin maybe but I think it would be better suited for something like [SU]

Comment: @HugoDozois Well, stackoverflow has a decent [autohotkey](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/autohotkey) base (at least one question per day), and this is a code problem. `[::{` ahk code example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me know if this is what you want?
<kbd>[</kbd> -> <kbd>{</kbd> and <kbd>{</kbd> -> <kbd>]</kbd>

```
#SingleInstance Force
#installKeybdHook
#Persistent

; Prefix the hotkeys with $ to prevent one hotkey from launching the other hotkey in a loop!

; + is the shift key, so +[ is {

;==== Switch [ AND { ====
$[::Send, {{}
$+[::Send, {[}

;====Switch ] AND } ====
$]::Send, {}}
$+]::Send, {]}

;====Switch , AND < ====
$,::Send, <
$+,::Send, {,}

;====Switch . AND > ====
$.::Send, >
$+.::Send, .
```

Comment: Thanks very much Robert Ilbrink, master of AHK! Work great.